# ssh clone not working for gitlab server from windows bash (client)

Tags: ssh

I have created a new repository in gitlab with one readme file created init (through gitlab web portal) and i have added the user to the git repository for accessing (push/merge). Now the gitlab server is an ubuntu machine and i am trying to clone the repo from a different pc(win10) git bash terminal. where i have already configured user settings.

added git user name ,email id , git remote url
generated ssh key in win 10 client and updated the same in gitlab account settings (web interface -add ssh key)

```
$ git clone ravi@1xx.1xx.2xx.29:8181/ravi/test-project.git  
Cloning into 'test-project'...  
ravi@1xx.1xx.2xx.29's password:  

fatal: '8181/ravi/test-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists.
```

---

can you please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: After regenerating the ssh key in windows bash and copying the rsa pub key in gitlab (account ssh key) the error got changed and now when i run the command ssh -Tv git@1xx.1xx.2xx.29 its not prompting for password but there is a message in the end which says.    Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!  
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0  
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0  
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1  
debug1: Exit status 0

Comment: It should be git clone git@git.YOUR_DOMAIN:YOUR_PROJECT.git
also make sure your ssh keys are inside .ssh folder and named id_rsa